# Can a symlink be edited to link to a different directory or file?

Tags: symlink

When I move a directory elsewhere, a symblink to it will become invalid.

The way I update a symlink `mylink` is first going into the directory, and then running `ln -s "$PWD" mylink`, and then `mv` `mylink` to the invalid symlink.

I can't create the new symlink in the same directory of the invalid symlink using the above `ln` command, because `ln: failed to create symbolic link`mylink': File exists, so I have to create it elsewhere and then there is an additional `mv` step.

I wonder if an existing invalid symlink can be edited directly, just like editing a text file in a text editor such as Emacs?

Answer (score 2):

```
ln -sf --no-target-directory /path/to/new/dir link
```

The option `--no-target-directory` (aka `-T`) prevents a new symlink to be created in the linked directory but is only available on GNU systems.

On FreeBSD or Apple OS/X, you'd use:

```
ln -sF /path/to/new/dir link
```

Comment: Good call - my testing was not thorough enough. :)

Comment: My manpage of `ln` says `--no-target-directory` means "treat LINK_NAME as a normal file". What does that mean?